# How to disable su for group by using pam_succeed_if?

Tags: su, pam

I'm trying to disable `su` for call group ids (`gid`) which equal or greater than *1003*.

My solution was as below but it didn't work. It failed for users who in lesser gids as well.

**Failed solution:**

Edit `/etc/pam.d/su`

Add line,

```
auth       required   pam_succeed_if.so quiet gid >= 1003
```

Any idea why this fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I miss understand the concept. Actually I thought gid represent the group ids of user who trying to run the su command. But it really represent the destination use's group ids.